# Can I enforce one field being dependent on another?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, constraint, check-constraints, data-validation

I would like to know if it's possible to have two fields (in this case `bit`s) in the same table where one is dependent on another. For example `Check2` may only be true if `Check1` is true.

**Note**: I'm trying to implement a constraint in an attempt to accomplish this, but so far failing.  I admit I have limited experience with constraints. This is a new database with little data, and there are no entries currently in the table where the conditions aforementioned are not true. That is, there is no record where `Check2` is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CHECK` constraint with a `CASE` expression. If `check2` is enabled, make sure `check1` is enabled too, otherwise you can default to a no-op ("checking" that check1 = check1). For simplicity I'm assuming these columns are *not* `NULL`able.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo
(
  check1 BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  check2 BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT ck_both CHECK (check1 = CASE WHEN check2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE check1 END)
);

INSERT dbo.foo DEFAULT VALUES;             -- 0,0 succeeds
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(1,0); -- succeeds
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(1,1); -- succeeds
GO
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(0,1); -- fails
```

To add this constraint to your existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename
  ADD CONSTRAINT ck_BothBits
  CHECK (check1 = CASE WHEN check2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE check1 END);
```

If the columns are `NULL`able (hopefully they aren't), you can say something like this (untested):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename
  ADD CONSTRAINT ck_BothBits
  CHECK (COALESCE(check1,0) = CASE 
    WHEN check2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE COALESCE(check1,0) END);
```

With that constraint in place:

```
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(NULL,NULL) -- succeeds
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(1,0);      -- succeeds
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(1,1);      -- succeeds
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(1,NULL);   -- succeeds
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(0,NULL);   -- succeeds
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(NULL,0);   -- succeeds
GO
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(0,1);      -- fails
GO
INSERT dbo.foo(check1,check2) VALUES(NULL,1);   -- fails
```

Comment: Nice answer! The constraint can also be written as CONSTRAINT ck_both CHECK (check2 = check1 & check2 )
..you know for the geeks :)

Comment: Brilliant, this is precisely what I needed, thank you. Your truth table is exactly what I wanted and yes of course my bits are non-nullable. Cheers! :)

Comment: @MisterMagoo I don't find that all that intuitive (I have a thing against bitwise in general anyway), plus it allows `NULL,1` if the columns are, in fact, `NULL`able.

Comment: @AaronBertrand fair enough, I found the CASE similarly difficult to grasp - people are different. Also, yes if NULL is an option, then it doesn't work.